# Python not iterating through all characters in a string (returns 'None'?)

Tags: python, list, loops, passwords

I'm trying to create a program that can iterate through characters in a password to determine if it meets specifications.
It needs at least seven characters, one uppercase character, one lowercase character, and one digit. Here's what I have:

```
def validPass(password): # >= 7 chars, one upper, one lower, one digit
for ch in password:
    if ch.isdigit():
        if ch.isupper():
            if ch.islower():
                if len(password) >= 7:
                    print ' Your password is valid.'
                else:
                    print 'Your password is not the correct length.'
    else:
        if ch.isupper():
            if ch.islower():
                if len(password) >= 7:
                    print ' Your password is valid.'
                    break
                else:
                    print 'Your password is not the correct length.'
            else:
                print 'Your password is not the correct length.'
        else:
            if ch.islower():
                if len(password) >= 7:
                    print ' Your password is valid.'
                    break
                else:
                    print 'Your password is not the correct length.'
            else:
                if len(password) >= 7:
                    print ' Your password is valid.'
                    break
                else:
                    print 'Your password is not the correct length.'
print validPass('$$$$$$$')
```

I know I'm barking up the wrong tree here. Also, when I submit '$$$$$$$', I get:

```
Your password is valid.
None
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems your only real test is `len(password) >= 7` why all the complicated nested `if` statements. Your not `return`ing anything so what would you expect `print validPass('$$$$$$$')` to print?

Answer (score 3):

Your function has no return statement, and you are trying to print the return value of the function, which is then None.

By the way, the block under the definition of you function should be indented.

See the difference from the example.

```
In [7]: def foo():
    return 'Hai'
   ...: 
In [8]: print foo()
Hai
In [9]: def foo():
    print 'Hai'
   ...:     
In [10]: print foo()
Hai
None
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dim said, your function is not returning anything so there is no need to call `print` on the function.

The problem with the approach of nested if statements is you would have to re-check other requirements in every pair of if/else blocks, which adds a lot of redundancy.

Here is another approach:

Keep tracker variables for the password requirements, initialized as `False`. Iterate through the characters in `password` and set the tracker variables to `True` if a requirement is satisfied.

Example:

```
def validPass(password):
    # tracker variables for the password requirements
    upper, lower, digit, length = False, False, False, False
    if len(password) >= 7:
        length = True
    for ch in password:
        if not lower and ch.islower():
            lower = True
        if not upper and ch.isupper():
            upper = True
        if not digit and ch.isdigit():
            digit = True
    # add print statements based on tracker variables if necessary
    # return True/False indicating password validity
    return all([upper, lower, digit, length])
```

Comment: OP: Thank you, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pwd = '1frSpuh`
```

Make some variables to store counts

```
>>> n_upper = 0
>>> n_lower = 0
>>> n_digit = 0
>>>
```

Iterate over the string and test each character, count the characters you are interested in

```
>>> for c in pwd:
    if c.isdigit():
        n_digit = n_digit + 1
    if c.islower():
        n_lower = n_lower + 1
    if c.isupper():
        n_upper = n_upper + 1
```

Apply the criteria

```
>>> if n_upper >= 1 and n_lower >= 1 and n_digit >= 1 and len(pwd) >=7:
    print('valid')
else:
    print('NOT!!!')
```

---

A nested conditional with mutually exclusive conditions like this

```
if ch.isdigit():
    if ch.isupper():
        if ch.islower():
```

will never *work* - a character cannot be all three.

---

Functions need a return statement to return something.